# Azure Functions Output to EventHub

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have a Azure Function built with NodeJS which receives data on a HTTP trigger, processes the data and then has to output the processed data to an Azure Event Hub to be ingested in Azure ADX. The output data is a JSON formatted payload.

> Flow:
> AZ Function (HTTP Trigger) -> AZ Event Hub -> AZ ADX

Using the EventHubProducerClient class (from NPM @azure/event-hubs), I am able to post the data to the event hub, which it then linked to ADX and the data is ingested. (This is typically the method followed if you build a app service).

I want to make use of the **baked-in** Azure Functions **Bindings** for eventHub (using the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle`), and I have set the settings:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": ["post"],
      "route": "upload"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },    
    {
      "type": "eventHub",
      "name": "outputEventHub",
      "eventHubName": "%AZEH_EVENTHUB_NAME%",
      "connection": "AZEH_CONNECTION_STRING",
      "direction": "out"
    }
}
```

*Ref: https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs.md#azure-event-hub-output-binding*

I have been trying to find the documentation on the dataType property in for the bindings (set up in function.json), but the best I could find was a document specifying the supported types, but not stating how to implement it. The best I saw was setting

`"dataType": "string"`

List of supported types:

- Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData
- String
- Byte array
- Plain-old CLR object (POCO)

*Ref: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output.md*

In my function that handles the trigger, I set the context binding to the JSON data like:

```
context.bindings.outputEventHub = jsonData;
```

but the data fails to pull through to ADX.

Anyone have some reference on how to set up a AZ function to ingest data in to ADX via Event Hub?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the data is send correctly from azure function to event hub. But when the ingestion happen at azure data explorer then you are facing the issue. Can you please confirm data format have you specified when you have configured the ingesting the data from event hub to azure data explore. Please refer to the [target table configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-hub#target-table) section. In case if your event hub have the different data format that what you are sending from your azure function then you could observe the issue. Please make sure you are serializing the data. In case if you are passing JSON object then you can leverage the JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourdaata) to pass the JSON message to the event hub.

Comment: Hi Mayank, I have set up the Data Format as JSON for the Target table, so this is fine.
The JsonConvert.SerializeObject function is to my understanding a newtonsoft (.net) function, which in this case is not applicable as this is a NodeJS built function.

Comment: Oh and I have checked the data is serialized as valid JSON.

Comment: Pieta - In case if you still facing the issue. Can you please send an email with subject line “Attn:Mayank” to AzCommunity[at]Microsoft[dot]com referencing this thread so I can review your setup to assist you.